# Install/upgrade ubuntu from another system

Tags: upgrade

I have a new Laptop with latest Ubuntu preinstalled on it, its 12.04. I have another laptop with Ubuntu 10.04 on it. What I lack is a fast internet connection. I want to upgrade my Ubuntu 10 laptop to a ubuntu 12 version. How is this possible without using internet connection? Can I move/copy the installation from the new laptop to the older one? Is there a way so that the newer laptop can upgrade the older one using a usb disk or dvd/cd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can buy a DVD here: http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=1027

Or maybe go to a library or somewhere else with decent free wifi? Unless the new laptop has the .iso somewhere then you're out of luck for the newer upgrading the older. You can search for it with:

```
sudo updatedb
locate *.iso
```